# Create a folder in BASH using string and date

Tags: bash

I would like to create a folder based on the system date in BASH. This is what I have done:

`mkdir $(date +"%d-%m-%Y")`

And its working fine, the output is `18-11-2012` but I need to concatenate this date with the string **backup_**

This is the output I want `backup_18-11-2012`

Comment: try this: mkdir "backup_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')"

Comment: @Lynch that is a perfectly good answer, even though the question was easy.  Move it to an answer and I'll delete mine as you were first by 8 seconds.

Comment: @RayToal No need to delete your answer. I will vote for both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this: 
`mkdir "backup_$(date +'%d-%m-%Y')"`

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this: `mkdir $(date +'backup_%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: Yes i discovered there are other ways also.

Comment: Ooops, I see in comments. Sorry :)